# Google Analytics API Unable to get for reporting via Azure Function App - getting 403 error

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am trying connect/get data from google Analytics API via Azure Function App to get some data back but getting the following error:

> 2022-09-27T08:54:39.251 [Error] Executed 'GetData' (Failed, Id=24a6ff24-c79c-4b5a-8be0-8222cd7652fe, Duration=230ms)Google.Apis.Requests.RequestErrorUser does not have any Google Analytics account. [403]Errors [Message[User does not have any Google Analytics account.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]]

Although it looks pretty straight forward that an account doesn't exist but this is not the case as I do have an account which is active.

I have the API enabled on the GA side. But I was wondering if there was another setting which is not turned on or another setting which is missed out.

Any help would be useful

Thanks
Jiten

Comment: Mind editing your question and including your code.  I would like to see how you are authorizing the application, using an azure function.

Answer (score 0):

> User does not have any Google Analytics account.

Is a very common error.  The user you are using to authorize the application does not currently have any google analytics accounts.

You should authorize the application with a user who has google analytics or grant that user access to a google analytics account.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this. 

Do you know the steps to Authorize a user or to grant access, I have access to the Google Console and can adjust any changes. 

I just need to know where to go.

Comment: This is something that is part of your code, [authorization](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization) it has nothing to do with having access to google console.  Your code needs to request authorization of the user, before you can access private user data.   Please edit your question and include your code.